# sql: how to do case with numeric type?

Tags: sql, db2

A very simple query - this one work because the type of column is `varchar`

```
SELECT
    title, length, 
    CASE length
       WHEN '=>2:00' THEN 'long' 
       WHEN '=<1:00' THEN 'short' 
       ELSE 'medium' 
    END medium 
FROM
    movies 
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

This one does not work, because the type of column is `numeric`:

```
SELECT  
    price, 
    CASE price 
       WHEN =< 7000 THEN 'not expensive' 
FROM cars;
```

> SQL0104N "<boolean_test>" error

So I tried `<`

```
SELECT 
    price, 
    CASE price 
       WHEN < 7000 THEN 'not expensive' 
FROM cars;
```

> SQLSTATE=42601 error

I tried the ''

```
SELECT 
    price, 
    CASE price 
       WHEN < '7000' THEN 'not expensive' 
FROM cars;
```

> SQLSTATE=42601 error

How to use case with numeric columns?

I'm on Db2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
With the numeric values the syntax is a little different
This works fine.

```
select name, price, case when price < 7000 then 'Not Expensive' else 'Expensive' end as Type from cars;
```

with a little complex syntax show cars from the cheapest to the most expensive.

```
select name, price, case when price between '5000' and '20000' then 'Cheapest' when price between 20000 and 40000 then 'Medium' else 'Expensive' end as Type from cars order by Type desc;
```

Comment: The issue isn'f numeric vs. non numeric.  It is an issue of wanting to use a range comparison, which can only be done with your version.

Comment: I have tried before the same syntax of the first query "select title,lenght, CASE ..." and give me only a lot of errors.